# Reliable Messaging accessible after adding ASMX web service via Service Reference

Tags: wcf

In VS2013 I have added Service Reference, not Web Reference, to existing legacy ASMX web service(s).

Does this somehow give this reference the ability to implement WCF features like Reliable Messaging, or any other new features of WCF?

I have done some reading and I think that at least for Reliable Messaging we do not magically get this ability, since as I understand it this feature has to be both enabled on the 'client' and 'server' side, ie both endpoints, and of course the old ASMX web services, the server in this case, don't support Reliable Messaging standard, even if I were to somehow configure the 'client' to do so.

I have been told by resident developers to add these old ASMX web services as a Service Reference as it gives the ability to do async calls and 'some' other configuration benefits, but I am not too sure about this from what I have now read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an adapter pattern. The way I am looking at it is more from design patterns perspective rather than WCF.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string toWhom);
}


public class Service : IService
{
    public string SayHello(string toWhom)
    {
        // consume the ASMX service here and return the result.

    }
}
```

in the binding you can use the features that are missing in ASMX.

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <reliableSession/>
      <security>
        <message />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the quick answer. Can I ask, is this something you have actually implemented in a commercial environment?

Comment: No. I've not. But I've surely used adapter pattern while replacing old functionality with new ones. 
Also use this solution carefully. I mean handle situations where the ASMX service has crashed using `FaultContract` etc.